# How to join 2 columns in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I hope you can help me, I want to combine 2 columns in one data table, I have an icon in one column and a folio number in another but I need the icon to come along with the folio number

**This is my html**

```
 <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="f4List" :items-per-page="10" class="elevation-0">
                <template v-slot:item.Minf="{ item }">
                <v-btn class="ma-2" outlined fab small color="secondary" v-on="on">
              <v-icon @click="reportItem(item)">mdi-file-document</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>

          </v-data-table>
```

**this is my js**

```
 headers: [
      { text: "", value: "Minf", sortable: true,},
      {
        text: "Iniciativa",
        value: 'folio', 
      },
      { text: "Estatus", value: "validado", sortable: false },
      { text: "Subdirecciones", value: "subdirecciones" },
      { text: "Fecha de Creación", value: "fecha_creacion" },
      //{ text: "Contratista", value: "contratista" },
      // { text: "Comentarios", value: "comentarios" },
      { text: "Fecha Validación", value: "fecha_validacion" },
      { text: "Acciones", value: "actions", sortable: false, align: "center" },
      { text: "Relacionar Iniciativa - Contrato", value: "generadores", sortable: false,
       align: "center", }
    ],
```

I would like the icon `mdi-file-document`  repeated in the heading of Iniciativa 
since I have the icon in one heading and the folio number in another

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXZAm.png)

Comment: Recommend adding more information about what you want